# Why value of property is kept when viewDidLoad is called again

Tags: objective-c

I have a property in class which default value is false

```
@implementation viewController1

BOOL variable1 = false;
```

When `viewDidLoad` first calls. Its value is false. Then I change it to true in a method. The next time viewDidLoad called the value of `variable1` was true.
but the default value is false. This means that it kept the value?
I can fix it but initializing this in viewDidLoad but I want to know the reason.

I initialize it again with these codes:

```
UINavigationController *nc1;

ViewController1 * viewController1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
    UITabBarItem *tab1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
    [tab1 setTitle: @”tab1”;
    nc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [viewController1 setTabBarItem:tab1];
    nc1.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: viewController1, nil];


[navigations addObject:nc1];

tabController.viewControllers = navigations;
```

Comment: If you want to reset all values then you should create new instance for the view controller. Calling viewdidload again wont reset all values.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Thanks. I added some details for how I initialize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a property (or an instance variable) in a class. That is a global variable in the file.

Instance variables need to be in curly braces:

```
@implementation viewController1 {
    BOOL variable1 = false;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // code
}

@end
```

Without the curly braces, `variable1` is just a global variable that has nothing to do with instances of the class. This is why it seems to keep its old value when you create a new view controller.