# different between defining variable with @property and in implementation in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I want to deffine a bool variable and set default value for it. I can do this

### First

```
@implementation ViewController1

BOOL var1 = false;
```

### Second

And I can add it in ViewController1.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL var1
```

Is it possible to set default value in second way

What is difference between these two?

Comment: probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/11478172/1214122

Comment: What is the purpose of `var1`?

Comment: @Willeke it is an example. I just want to learn it. Why should not use with first way?

Comment: Is your question how an instance variable is different from a property (which you ask in the question itself) or reasons to use one over the other (which you ask in your comment above)?

Comment: @holex @DavidRönnqvist the first `var1` is a global variable, not an ivar.

Comment: Note that the answer to "how an instance variable is different from a property" will depend slightly on the variables type (if it's a primitive—like `BOOL` or `NSInteger`—or if it's an Objective-C object—like `NSString`, `NSArray`, or `UIView`). Consider updating your question to mention if this difference matters to you.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Thanks. Yes. and could you please look at this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947759/why-value-of-property-is-kept-when-viewdidload-is-called-again

Comment: @Willeke I'm wasn't sure if that was the OP's intention or if the OP meant to declare an instance variable instead.

Comment: @ Willeke you mean that with first way I created a global variable which is not related to a specific class?

Comment: Yes, an ivar is declared inside `{}`.

Comment: @Willeke, soooo, is that question about why one should do _encapsulation_ rather than _polluting the global namespace_...?

Comment: @helex I actually didn't know that with first way I declare a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way is global. That means you have potential to disturb other library or framework that you use in your app.

Second way is the correct way to do it but of course it limits to only your class. Also memorywise, is better.

Also, if you want "global" variable, use singleton. :D